# Can I assign shortcut to popular search (search for all my classes in project) in Eclipse Search (ctrl+H, Java Search)

Tags: java, eclipse

I often need to search one and the same thing. Can I automate opening Search Dialogue and entering search data and assign it to shortcut?

Is there anything built-in in Eclipse, besides just a macro plugin?

Comment: If you `often need to search one and the same thing` why don't you not know where it is?

Comment: Not that I know of... I often use the previous input values, which I find very useful (especially for 'File Search', with a file name pattern), and it works directly with the mousewheel for faster usage.

Comment: It would help to know specifically what you're searching for. I often use `Ctrl+Shift+T` to search for types, but that won't work other things.

Comment: As said, `Ctrl+Shift+T` is for types, `Ctrl+Shift+R` is for file resources. By selecting something and pressing `Ctrl+Shift+U`, you'll search occurences of that within currently open file. Most of these also has a list of previously searched things you can quickly go to, as well as some sort autocomplete support.